# c# generic interface collection does not compile

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, constraints

I am having trouble with creating a collection of my generic interface.

here is my generic interface:

```
public interface IPlayerInputHandler<out TDataStore, out TStateContext, in TPlayerInput, out TServerOutput>
    where TDataStore : DataStore
    where TStateContext : IStateContext
    where TPlayerInput : IPlayerInput
    where TServerOutput : IServerOutputPacket
{
    TDataStore DataStore { get; }
    TStateContext Context { get; }

    TServerOutput HandleInput(ushort serverTick, TPlayerInput playerInput, Guid CharacterId);
}
```

Here is a base class which my `PlayerInputHandler

```
public abstract class ServerPlayerInputHandler<TPlayerInput, TServerOutput> : IPlayerInputHandler<DataStore, StateContext, TPlayerInput, TServerOutput>
    where TPlayerInput : IPlayerInput
    where TServerOutput : IServerOutputPacket
{
    public DataStore DataStore { get; private set; }
    public StateContext Context { get; private set; }

    protected readonly ServerStateManager ServerStateManager;
    protected readonly ServerPlayersManager PlayersManager;

    protected ServerPlayerInputHandler(DataStore dataStore, StateContext context, ServerStateManager serverStateManager, ServerPlayersManager playersManager)
    {
        DataStore = dataStore;
        Context = context;
        ServerStateManager = serverStateManager;
        PlayersManager = playersManager;
    }
    public abstract TServerOutput HandleInput(ushort serverTick, TPlayerInput playerInput, Guid CharacterId);
```

}

And an example of an PlayerInputHandler:

```
public class AddItemInputHandler : ServerPlayerInputHandler<AddItemInput, AddItemPacket>
{
    public AddItemInputHandler(DataStore dataStore, StateContext context, ServerStateManager serverStateManager, ServerPlayersManager serverPlayersManager)
        : base(dataStore, context, serverStateManager, serverPlayersManager)
    {
    }

    public override AddItemPacket HandleInput(ushort serverTick, AddItemInput playerInput, Guid playerId)
    {
        var instanceId = Extensions.GenerateShortId();

        Context.Mutator.CharacterAddItem(playerId, playerInput.ItemId, instanceId);
        var aip = new AddItemPacket(playerInput.ItemId, instanceId, playerId, serverTick);

        return aip;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to create a collection as follows:

```
private Dictionary<PlayerInputType, IPlayerInputHandler<IPlayerInput, IServerOutputPacket, IPlayerInput, IServerOutputPacket>> _playerInputHandlers;
```

and be able to add `AddItemInputHandler` to the collection.

As you can see from my generic interface, the method it exposes also relies on the `TPlayerInput` and `TServerOutput` and I do not wish to create a method which accepts the `IPlayerInput` or `TServerOutput` because it could cause boxing and unboxing.

Do you guys have any suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: The first question I'd ask is: Does this really need to be a generic class? Why can't it just be a class that takes IPlayerInput and returns IServerOutputPacket?

Comment: @CallumBradbury If the method will receive IPlayerInput it means that my struct implementations of IPlayerInput will be boxed - a behavior that I try to prevent.

I should also mention, this area of the code is performance critical therefore I chose to use structs (The data is relatively small and it meets the requirements of using structs instead of classes)

Answer (score 0):

First, name a class Addsomething is a bad way. I think.

To be honest, I don't quite understand what you want to do. Nevertheless let's try a bit.

I have created a class for the collection

```
> public class PlayerInputHandlers : Dictionary<
>                             PlayerInputType,
>                             IPlayerInputHandler<
>                                 IPlayerInput,
>                                 IServerOutputPacket,
>                                 IPlayerInput,
>                                 IServerOutputPacket>
>                         > {
> 
>     public void AddItemInputHandler<T, U>(T PlayerInputType, U PlayerInputHandler) 
>         where T : PlayerInputType
>         where U: IPlayerInputHandler<IPlayerInput, IServerOutputPacket, IPlayerInput, IServerOutputPacket>
>     {
>         this.Add(PlayerInputType, PlayerInputHandler);
>     } 
> 
> }
```

This is all my interfaces

```
public class DataStore : IPlayerInput
public interface IPlayerInput
public interface IPlayerInputHandler<out TDataStore, out TStateContext, in TPlayerInput, out TServerOutput>
        where TDataStore : IPlayerInput
        where TStateContext : IStateContext
        where TPlayerInput : IPlayerInput
        where TServerOutput : IServerOutputPacket
public interface IServerOutputPacket : IStateContext
public interface IServerPlayerInputHandler<TPlayerInput, TServerOutput>
        where TPlayerInput : IPlayerInput
        where TServerOutput : IServerOutputPacket
public interface IStateContext
public class PlayerInputType
public abstract class ServerPlayerInputHandler<TPlayerInput, TServerOutput> : IPlayerInputHandler<DataStore, StateContext, TPlayerInput, TServerOutput>, IServerPlayerInputHandler<TPlayerInput, TServerOutput> 
        where TPlayerInput : IPlayerInput
        where TServerOutput : IServerOutputPacket
public class ServerPlayersManager
public class ServerStateManager
public class StateContext : IStateContext
```

Comment: I never thought of turning `PlayerInputHandlers` to inherit from a dictionary, this seems interesting, I will try it out and update.

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I tried to integrate the solution the you purposed, and yet I receive the same error,
here is my PoC: https://ibb.co/dPD9SDG

Comment: as for what I'm trying to achieve:

I am trying to abstract the command handlers, that the client can send to the server

So in this case the `AddItemInputHandler` the handler handles `AddItem` commands
and thus `AddItemHandler` should be constrained to that type of command

Comment: Sorry bro, here it's the shutdown. Can't see your problem for several weeks. Coronavirus wins.